# Laravel Nova - how to use Laravel error pages

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I wonder what is the best way to make Nova use Laravel (default or customized) error pages without duplicating them.

(I found the 404 page in this path: `/nova/resources/js/views/Error404.vue`)

This is the only article I found, but I don't see how it can help me:
https://medium.com/laravel-nova/laravel-nova-custom-error-pages-bd382e7007d7